# how to find the index of the first non-whitespace character in a string in python?

Tags: python, string

Scenario:

```
>>> a='   Hello world'
index = 3
```

In this case the "H" index is '3'. But I need a more general method such that for any string variable 'a' takes I need to know the index of the first character?

Alternative scenario:

```
>>> a='\tHello world'
index = 1
```

Comment: Spaces are technically characters, just so you know.

Comment: It should be `1` in your second example, right?

Comment: How does `lstrip` not work in this case?

Comment: What do you want if the string is empty or all white space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean the first non-whitespace character, I'd use something like this ...

```
>>> a='   Hello world'
>>> len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
3
```

Another one which is a little fun:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(str.isspace,a))
3
```

But I'm willing to bet that the first version is faster as it does essentially this exact loop, only in C -- Of course, it needs to construct a new string when it's done, but that's essentially free.

---

For completeness, if the string is empty or composed of entirely whitespace, both of these will return `len(a)` (which is invalid if you try to index with it...)

```
>>> a = "foobar"
>>> a[len(a)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: I already did this and it works if the left characters are spaces. What if the variable as 'a='/tHello World'' in this case the lstrip wont work.

Comment: I needs a more general method

Comment: @karthik You should've mentioned this in your question. See another answer.

Comment: @karthik -- How does this not work for `a='\tHello World'`?  It gives `1` (as it should)

Comment: @ mgilson you are right my bad it would work. I did wrong calculation error :)

Comment: @downvoter -- If you leave an explanation about *why* you think this answer is inadequate, I'll happily try to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a='   Hello world'
>>> re.search(r'\S',a).start()
3
>>> a='\tHello world'
>>> re.search(r'\S',a).start()
1
>>>
```

Function to handle the cases when the string is empty or contains only white spaces:

```
>>> def func(strs):
...     match = re.search(r'\S',strs)
...     if match:
...         return match.start()
...     else:
...         return 'No character found!'
...     
>>> func('\t\tfoo')
2
>>> func('   foo')
3
>>> func('     ')
'No character found!'
>>> func('')
'No character found!'
```

Comment: @kirelagin Any advantages of `\S` over `\w`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- you could pass a string like `'    .foo'` (`\w` misses the `.`)

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'` for empty or whitespace strings.

Comment: @dansalmo yes, but that can be easily handled using either an if-else or a try-except block.

Comment: @downvoter please care to explain your downvote, so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
a = '   Hello world'
a.index(a.lstrip()[0])
=> 3
```

It'll work as long as the string contains at least one non-space character. We can be a bit more careful and check this before:

```
a = '    '
-1 if not a or a.isspace() else a.index(a.lstrip()[0])
=> -1
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather have the Exception since `-1` is a perfectly acceptable index, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @dansalmo this won't work: `a.index(a.lstrip()[0:])` it'll return `0` for a string such as this: `'  '`, which is not correct

Comment: @mgilson it depends on the convention, it's fine if we only allow returned indexes to be >= 0

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  This is the classic `a.find` vs. `a.index` debate.  Personally, I never use `a.find` because I need to validate the output.  I'd rather handle an Exception than validate (akin to EAFP vs. LBYL)

Comment: `a.index(a.lstrip()[0]) if a.lstrip() else -1` will work with any string.

Comment: @dansalmo that's shorter, but requires one extra string to be created. I'll stick with mine :)

Comment: @mgilson I guess I'm a LBYL kind of guy :)

Comment: @Oscar, one extra string is a small price to pay for improved readability. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another method, just for fun... 
Using a special function!

```
>>> def first_non_space_index(s):
    for idx, c in enumerate(s):
        if not c.isspace():
            return idx


>>> a = '   Hello world'        
>>> first_non_space_index(a)
3
```

Comment: maybe rename it to `first_non_space_index` ... the name you have makes it seem like you'll return `'H'`

Comment: Maybe you should deal with the case that the whole string is whitespace. In this case, you return None. I recommend `return len(s)` behind the loop.

Comment: @Fabian By default all functions return None. So by virtue of not finding an index, None would be returned anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following mgilson's answer, you can use lstrip to strip any characters you'd like -

```
unwanted = ':!@#$%^&*()_+ \t\n'
a= '  _Hello world'
res = len(a) - len(a.lstrip(unwanted))
```

Comment: It does, but I thought, from karthik's comment, that he wanted a more general method (seems like he didn't after all)

Comment: What I'm saying is that what you have is *less general* than a bare `lstrip()` (and probably slightly less efficient) since python uses a different algorithm for `lstrip()` and `lstrip(argument)`.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer so it will at least offer more functionality.